# Retrieve rows from multiple entires for a given identifier and one column value from within a set of values only

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery, relational-database

I have a database table used for storing audit like the one below (It is only a simplistic representation of actual table where STATUS can have one of the many values)

```
ID | STUDENT_ID | COURSE_ID | STATUS
1  |     5      | 12        | Enrolled
2  |     5      | 12        | In-Progress
3  |     2      | 12        | Enrolled
4  |     2      | 12        | Completed
5  |     5      | 12        | Completed
6  |     2      | 14        | Enrolled
```

I need to find all the records for a given STUDENT_ID & COURSE_ID pair as identifier, where STATUS belongs to Enrolled & Completed(i.e There are 2 records for each Enrolled & Completed status or only a single record for either Enrolled or Completed status).

Note- There should not exist an entry for given STUDENT_ID & COURSE_ID where STATUS is other than Enrolled & Completed.

Output table -

```
ID | STUDENT_ID | COURSE_ID | STATUS
3  |     2      | 12        | Enrolled
4  |     2      | 12        | Completed
6  |     2      | 14        | Enrolled
```

**Update -**  If I have another entry for STUDENT_ID 2 that has status In-Progress, it should still return me the course where Status is Enrolled and Completed.

```
ID | STUDENT_ID | COURSE_ID | STATUS
1  |     5      | 12        | Enrolled
2  |     5      | 12        | In-Progress
3  |     2      | 12        | Enrolled
4  |     2      | 12        | Completed
5  |     5      | 12        | Completed
6  |     2      | 14        | Enrolled
7  |     2      | 14        | In-Progress
```

Output table -

```
ID | STUDENT_ID | COURSE_ID | STATUS
3  |     2      | 12        | Enrolled
4  |     2      | 12        | Completed
```

Comment: I don't understand your output student 5 has enrolled and completed course 12 so why not in output and student 6 has not completed course 14?

Comment: @P.Salmon - Because for course 12, student 5 also has a record In-Progress status. For any Student-Course pair in should either have Enrolled or Completed or both Enrolled & Completed status only.

Answer (score 2):

Using a left join with a null test

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(ID int, STUDENT_ID int, COURSE_ID int, STATUS varchar(20));
insert into t values
(1  ,     5      , 12        , 'Enrolled'),
(2  ,     5      , 12        , 'In-Progress'),
(3  ,     2      , 12        , 'Enrolled'),
(4  ,     2      , 12        , 'Completed'),
(5  ,     5      , 12        , 'Completed'),
(6  ,     2      , 14        , 'Enrolled');


select t.* from t
left join
(select  student_id,course_id,count(*) from t where status not in('enrolled','completed') group by student_id,course_id) s
on t.STUDENT_ID = s.student_id and t.course_id = s.course_id 
where s.student_id is null;

+------+------------+-----------+-----------+
| ID   | STUDENT_ID | COURSE_ID | STATUS    |
+------+------------+-----------+-----------+
|    3 |          2 |        12 | Enrolled  |
|    4 |          2 |        12 | Completed |
|    6 |          2 |        14 | Enrolled  |
+------+------------+-----------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just exclude `STUDENT_ID` & `COURSE_ID`s where `In-Progress` status found :

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1 
                  from table t1 
                  where t1.student_id = t.student_id and 
                        t1.course_id = t.course_id and t1.status = 'In-Progress'
                 );
```

Comment: As I have mentioned STATUS can have one of the many values and excluding every other value is not ideal for me. I somehow have to include only theses two values in my query.

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned you only need these two status - 'Enrolled','Completed'
You can achieve your goal with Sub-Query

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM   students t 
WHERE  student_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT student_id 
                          FROM   students 
                          WHERE  status NOT IN ( 'Enrolled', 'Completed' ));
```

Answer (score 0):

use distinct and sub-query

```
 select distinct * from your_table 
    where STUDENT_ID not in 
      (  select STUDENT_ID from your_table 
         where STATUS in ('In-Progress')
      )
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6d650/1

```
ID  STUDENT_ID  COURSE_ID   STATUS
3     2         12          Enrolled
4     2         12          Completed
6     2         14          Enrolled
```

Another way

```
select t1.* from
(
select * from yourtable 

) as t1

left join  
(
select * from yourtable
             where STATUS  in ('In-Progress')
) as t2 on t1.STUDENT_ID=t2.STUDENT_ID
where t2.id is null
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6d650/7

```
ID  STUDENT_ID  COURSE_ID   STATUS
3     2            12     Enrolled
4     2            12     Completed
6     2            14     Enrolled
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to return couples of (STUDENT_ID, COURSE_ID) where status is `Enrolled` or `Completed`, but not anything else:

```
select
  student_id,
  course_id
from
  students
group by
  student_id,
  course_id
having
  sum(status in ('Enrolled', 'Completed'))>0
  and sum(status not in ('Enrolled','Completed'))=0
```

then you can extract all columns with this:

```
select *
from students
where
  (students_id, course_id) in (
    ..the select query above...
  )
```